# Passing references in c++

Tags: c++

I am writing a program for overloading "[ ] " operator on arrays .Here is my code

```
 / / A safe array example.
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    using namespace std;

    class atype {
      int a[3];
    public:
      atype(int i, int j, int k) {
        a[0] = i;
        a[1] = j;
        a[2] = k;
      }
      int &operator[](int i);
    };

    // Provide range checking for atype.
    int &atype::operator[](int i)
    {
      if(i<0 || i> 2) {
        cout << "Boundary Error\n";
        exit(1);
      }
      return a[i];
    }

    int main()
    {
      atype ob(1, 2, 3);

      cout << ob[1]; // displays 2
      cout << " ";

      ob[1] = 25; // [] appears on left
      cout << ob[1]; // displays 25

      ob[3] = 44; // generates runtime error, 3 out-of-range

      return 0;
    }
```

In the class we are declaring as

```
int &operator[](int i);
```

and outside the class it is defined as

```
int &atype::operator[](int i)
```

It should be `int atype::&operator[](int i)`
but it is giving me error.

```
1>c:\users\abc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\[]overl\[]overl\[]overl.cpp(17): error C2589: '&' : illegal token on right side of '::'
1>c:\users\abc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\[]overl\[]overl\[]overl.cpp(17): warning C4091: '' : ignored on left of 'int' when no variable is declared
1>c:\users\abc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\[]overl\[]overl\[]overl.cpp(17): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '::'
1>c:\users\abc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\[]overl\[]overl\[]overl.cpp(17): error C2059: syntax error : '::'
1>c:\users\abc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\[]overl\[]overl\[]overl.cpp(18): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\abc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\[]overl\[]overl\[]overl.cpp(18): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

But when I tried `int &atype::operator[](int i)`
it worked.Could anybody explain that are we passing reference to class or operator[](int i)

Comment: `int atype::&operator[](int i)` is wrong, `int &atype::operator[](int i)` is correct. Why did you think the first one was correct?

Comment: You are not passing a reference a reference to the class, or to operator[]. You are **returning** a reference from operator[]. That's why the **return** type is `int&`.

Comment: Read a book and have a look at std::array.

Comment: I am reading a book .Don't be rude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general syntax is

```
<return type> class-name :: function-name (argument-list)
```

In your case the return type is a *reference to an integer* i.e. `int &`

`int &atype::operator[](int i)` is only the correct syntax

Answer (score 1):

Your `operator[]` returns a reference to the element requested by index. In this case your array is of `int` type so it will be a reference-to-an-int, ie: `int&` as a return value.